# comma in csv data in ssis package

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, data-conversion, flatfiledestination

i am passing data from database to csv file i.e oledbsource to flat file destination. in few of the columns data, it contains comma value. currently the comma is separating the data into different columns. Instead of replacing the comma with other value, can we retain it in column data without the data being separated in different columns ?

Comment: Why replace anything? Just set the correct separator and text qualifier in the destination's settings. Not my downvote, but ... what did you try?

Comment: I am passing the data from oledb datasource to flatfile destination. Currently the delimeter is comma and the text qualifier is none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Text Qualifier = " then this will wrap each text field in double quotes

So if the field has a comma it will still work.

Eg Field = Jones, Fred will be saved as "prev field","Jones, Fred", "next field", 1, 2 etc